# Is there a better way to use a CountUpDownLatch than Await?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I'm using a count up/down latch to keep a program limited to 6 threads, it works but what I really want is to always have 6 threads running. So that when one thread dies, another one starts up. With the implementation below, it only creates 6 new threads at a time, whenever the timeout expires.

Any suggestions on how to struct my loop to accomplish this?

```
int numThreads = 6;

CountUpDownLatch threadCounter = new CountUpDownLatch();

for(int t = 1; t <= numThreads; t++) {
    while(list.hasNext()) {

    new Thread(new ThreadController("processData",list.next())).start();

    threadCounter.countUp();
    }
    try {
        threadCounter.await(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Comment: Use a [FixedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an executor service which contains 6 threads like so,

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    exec.submit(() -> System.out.println("Hello"));
}
exec.shutdown();
```

You can either pass a `Runnable` or a `Callable` to the `submit` method of the `ExecutorService`. Here I have passed a lambda function as a `Runnable` which is valid starting from Java8. In your case you may do it like so,

```
exec.submit(new ThreadController("processData",list.next()));
```

Comment: So I don't need the latch, do I still implement runnable? Confused on the scope of Executors

Comment: Latch is no longer needed. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I updated my code and the program creates 6 threads, but after a min it creates 6 more before the others have finished. How does it know a thread has ended? It seems I might not be signaling something.

Comment: The `Thread` terminates once it completes the execution of it's `run` method.

Comment: Ok I'm getting different behavior, I created a new question to show my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632916/fixed-thread-pool-is-exiting-immediately-not-processing-threads

Comment: The given code seems work perfectly for me. All the 10 tasks are started and then completed as expected.