# Fixed Thread Pool is exiting immediately, not processing threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Trying to understand fixed thread pools I made this test code, which revealed the below results, contrary to what I thought it would do:

```
Thread Start: 1
Thread Start: 2
Thread Start: 0
```

That's it. No "Thread End" messages and only 3 threads were started.

I expected and I want all 10 tasks to complete.

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
    exec.execute(new TestThread(c));
}
exec.shutdown();
```

---

```
public class TestThread implements Runnable {

    private int counter;

    public TestThread (int counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread Start: " + counter);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Thread End: " + counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works good. but you must call exec.shutdown() after finish work with exec.

Comment: @Amin `shutdown` will "lock" executor and will start killing idle threads. It is not required to call it in order to "make it work"

Comment: What do you mean it works good? It prints what I showed. Where are the other 7 threads, and why didn't it print "Thread end"

Comment: @Moonstone not *other 7 threads* as you have only 3 threads, but "other tasks*

Comment: because I check it and work. about shutdown, as I know if you didn't call that, it is wait for accept more runnable and callable and program doesn't finish.

Comment: @Antoniossss thank you for the correction, so why didn't the other tasks start?

Comment: Isnt that what I wrote? Pool will live unless threads are non daemon (or the other way aroung;/ crap)

Comment: @Antoniossss  I want all tasks to complete, how to do that?

Comment: The code you shared, works just like that. There must be something in overall context.

Comment: @Antoniossss I'm showing everything, this is Java 8 in Intellij. Any ideas?

Comment: Ye, show me the whole code.

Comment: Try to add `exec.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOUR);` to block your main thread until all submitted tasks are done

Comment: Please make a [MCVE] that shows all the code in a form that can be run. what is posted is jumbled up. what is exec.shutdown() supposed to be part of? We should be able to take the code, paste it into an editor, save it and run it;

Comment: @Nathan Hughes  exec.shutdown() was an edit added manually to show I did try that, i added to the wrong section by mistake. The rest is cut and paste. I have no idea what you mean by "jumbled up".

Comment: @Ivan - that solved it! If you make an answer below, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec.shutdown()` doesn't block main thread. If you need to wait for all submitted tasks to finish you need to call `exec.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOUR);` (of course with timeout that makes sense for your application) after call to `exec.shutdown();`.

```
/**
 * Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown
 * request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is
 * interrupted, whichever happens first.
 */
boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
    throws InterruptedException;
```

Comment: that was my problem, in the context of the larger application, system.exit() is called, I wrongly assumed the program would wait for the thread queue.